# Permalinks don't work on nested Wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress install on AWS Ubuntu, it's installed in /var/www/

Now I am trying to add a help section to my site, and I want to use a different theme so I have to install another copy of WP, I've put it inside /var/www/help/

Everything works fine with the default URLs (?page_id=XX) but when I change in Settings the permalinks to Post Name, the site breaks. Now when going to a page or a post I am getting a 404 of the main site - not the nested install.

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

**/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

**/var/www/help/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /help/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /help/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You know that .htacces are a overhead for Apache? If you have access to the httpd.conf write everything in there.

Comment: I used your hint and this actually solved my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution using Christian Gartner's hint - deleted .htaccess from /var/www/help/ and changed /etc/apache2/http.conf to the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/help/>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /help/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /help/index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

This solved the issue for me.